# How hide an Form of a dll file?

Tags: forms, delphi, dll

I have a dll file that contains several Forms.

I have a reference to main function in console application that loads this dll.

I want hide main Form of dll file, but all attempts until now was without sucess.

I tried several ways for this, but nothing that I tried worked, except for hide from taskbar.

This is my code:

*Main form on dll*

```
   unit Conectar;

    interface

    uses
      Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes {.......};

    type
      TForm1 = class(TForm)
      procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);

    private
        { Private declarations }
      public
        { Public declarations }
          procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
      end;

    procedure TForm1.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
    begin
         inherited;

         params.exstyle := params.exstyle and not WS_EX_APPWINDOW or WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW;

         end;


procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin

ShowWindow(Form1.Handle,SW_HIDE);

end;
```

*Dll*

```
library DLL;

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Conectar,
  vcl.Forms,
  Classes;

{$R *.res}

procedure ShowDllForm; stdcall;
begin
  Form1 := TForm1.Create(nil);
  try
    Form1.ShowModal;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Form1);
  end;
end;

exports
 ShowDllForm;

begin
end.
```

*Console application*

```
{$APPTYPE GUI}

    var
      Msg: TMsg;

      procedure ShowDllForm;stdcall;
        external 'DLL.dll' name 'ShowDllForm';

    begin
     CoInitialize(nil);
     ShowDllForm;

    CoUninitialize;

    end.
```

Comment: If you want to hide it, why show it?

Comment: Um... Don't call `ShowDllForm`? (Your questions are enjoyable, BTW. *How do I show a form from a DLL?*, followed by *How do I not show a form from a DLL?*, within a couple hours of each other. What's next?)

Comment: @KenWhite, On my last question, is necessary execute the `Form1` (main Form) for my software works fine. But now, I want execute, but without user can see this Form. So, you have some suggestion for solve this (or try solve), friend? If this Form not be showed, my software don't works. Because others forms in dll file depends this main form.

Comment: Hide a Form of a dll file is more hard than of a VCL Form :-(. I don't know how do.

Comment: Yes, I have some suggestions. If your app relies on a GUI, don't make it a console app. If it doesn't, don't include GUI windows. If it needs to run in the background, make it a service. If you need a UI to control that service, write it as a separate app and use interprocess communication for them to talk to each other. Other than that, it's totally unclear what you're trying to do, and without more information I can't offer any help; your entire design seems wrong to me.

Comment: @KenWhite, OK, then, based in your last comment, finally don't is possible hide a Form of a dll file if the application that calls this dll file is a console application. Is correct?

Comment: No, I did not say it's not possible. I'm saying I can't help you because it's unclear what you're trying to do, but from what you've said in both your questions my opinion is that your entire design is wrong. If you need to display a form, you should not be using a console application. It's unclear why you are doing so.

Comment: Ken's right. What you are describing is a poor design. Forms are for displaying. You want something non visual. A form is the wrong thing.

Comment: I have some `TClientSocket` components and `TTimer` on main Form (Fomr1) in this dll file. So, how activate they, without show main form of dll file? Already tried several way, but don't works :-(. [eg](http://pastebin.com/haYVaVVc) This way, will cause a `EAccessViolation` on dll part.

Comment: You don't need a form for any of that. You need a message loop. That's all.

Comment: I have search very much for this and found [this suggestion](http://pastebin.com/hhZVU7ae). But causes a exception. Now I will test this on host program (.exe that will load dll) as a VCL Form, and not as a console application as done before.

Comment: You really don't need a form here. In fact it's a really bad idea to have one. Don't have any VCL at all. For the timer use SetTimer.

Comment: @David, I really need hide this Form, this for me is the better idea instead of create codes for activates components that are of main Form design and not is only a simple Timer :-). Now say me, really exist some way that works for hide completally a form in a dll file? Or I'm losing my time with this (not is possible this that want)? Relative to all that I found, the suggestion more consistent for this was this last link in my comment above.

Comment: You don't need a form.

Comment: This question isn't useful to anyone else and I suggest you delete it. Your are badly mistaken in using a form for non-visual purposes. You don't want to heed the sound advice to use the right tools for the job. That's fine, but it's not going to lead to anything useful for future readers.

Comment: @David, OK, thank you for your advices, but this works very fine to me :-)

Comment: It just seems fine, but doesn't it smell bad? Using a visual component for non-visual purposes. And it's so trivially easy to do it without the form. Just strip out the form. Put the objects in a non-visual class. Run a message loop.

Comment: Anyway,  the dll when executed always will be the host.exe when seeing across task manager.

Comment: This solution not is the better, but works when host.exe is a program created normally in Delphi, C++, C#..., and have a infinite loop, but if you try make a dll injection for example, the Form will always finalized on another host (like notepad.exe, calc.exe...) :-( . Or I'm wrong about this? (Form always finalized on other host.exe, In view of that this other host also always stays running :-)  )

Comment: I think you are going about this the wrong way, but you disagree. Which is fine. Good luck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SOLUTION:

***Dll***

```
 procedure ShowDllForm; stdcall;
    begin
      Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
      ShowWindow(Application.Handle, SW_HIDE);
    end;
```

***Console application***

```
var
      Msg: TMsg;

begin

   ShowDllForm; 

while GetMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0) do begin
              TranslateMessage(Msg);
              DispatchMessage(Msg);

end;

end.
```

OR

on dll file in `FormActivate` event:

```
Form1.Hide;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);
end;
```